# Keras input layer shape matches any shape given by generator

Tags: python, keras, generator, shapes, mismatch

I found this strange behaviour that keras trains without error although the shapes do not match

```
n = Input(shape=(16, 1))
d = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(n)
m = Model(n, d)

def get_gen():
    for i in range(10):
         x = np.random.rand(32, 28, 1)
         yield x, np.ones(32)

m.fit(get_gen()) # Works strangely
m.fit(np.random.rand(32, 28, 1), np.ones(32)) # Not working reasonbly
```

So why input shape is not respected in case of generator, is there implicit broadcasting, I really can not comprehend this behaviour as it should raise error when input shapes mismatch

Comment: I have put a print command inside keras at the place the error occurs. So in the second example, it compares the sizes `16` with `28`, doesn't match. While in the first, it compares `16` with `None`, so it passes the test

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But where None came from?. If this is a general case then when using generator the defined input shape is not taken at all, so could this be true? @AndrzejO how did you manage to include print to check the match bcz I tried callback on_batch_begin but could not do it.

Comment: My guess is, that it cannot determine: is the data batched, with a batch size of 28 and shape (1), or not batch with shape (28,1) ? So it doesn't check this dimension. While when providing x and y, it knows that the data is not batched

Comment: I suspect in this case then, that there is no actual training at all. Keras jumps over the input checking in the generator and consequently no data is based to the model to be trained (bcz there no way to broadcast (28, 1) to (16, 1)) which results at the end by a model that has not trained at all.

Comment: The model receives data. You can add a lambda layer after the input layer, and print out the data: `l = Lambda(lambda x: tf.print(x.shape) and x)(n)`